# Finding an unknown angle in a right-angled triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

I've used  cosine & sine rule, and after playing around with them, I'll always end up with an equation involving $\sin\theta,\cos\theta$ and other weird (and wonderful expressions). I've approached the question in many different ways: by showing $AD=x$ (since $\angle DAC=\angle DCA=30^\circ$ it forms an isosceles triangle),  also tried to show $\sin\theta=1/2$ ... but I never got the correct answer.

This has been bothering me for weeks.

Thanks in advance[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQope.jpg)

Comment: I don't know about others, but i will certainly help you maintain your friendship if only you include a bit more details.

Comment: This is all the question says, it's a question from a Chinese High-school Maths exam paper but I've just translated it to English :)

Comment: Try showing that  $D$ is the midpoint of $BC$

Comment: If I voted to close, my argument would be it is more suitable for the Chemistry SE 

Comment: "by showing AD=x(since DAC=DCA=30∘ it forms an isosceles triangle)" Since$DCA = 30$ is *precisely what you are trying to prove you *don't* know that $DAC=DCA$ at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Drop altitude DT = $y$. Then, AT = DT$\>\cot30$ = $\sqrt3 y$. From similar triangles CDT and CBA, we have $\frac{BA}{DT}=\frac{AC}{TC}$, or

$$\frac xy = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2} +\sqrt3y} {\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}
=1+\frac {\sqrt3y}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}
$$

Rearrange to get $(x-2y)(x^3+2y^3)=0$, 
which yields $x=2y$. Thus, $\sin\theta = \frac12$ and $\theta =30$.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! I tried using similar triangles but never got as far as this! Thanks for the enlightenment.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

In right $\Delta BAC$ $$\sin\theta=\frac{AB}{BC}=\frac{x}{BC}\implies BC=x\csc\theta$$
$$BD=BC-CD=x\csc\theta-x \quad \angle ADB=\theta+30^\circ$$

Using Sine rule in $\Delta ADB$ as folows
$$\frac{\sin(\theta+30^\circ)}{x}=\frac{\sin60^\circ}{x\csc\theta-x}$$
$$2\sin(\theta+30^\circ)(1-\sin\theta)=\sqrt3 \sin\theta$$
Solving above equation for $0<\theta<90^\circ$, we get $\color{blue}{\theta=30^\circ}$